# struts2 optiontransfer: how automatically select all

Tags: jquery, struts2

how to automatically select all in right side box of struts2 optiontransfer. since I get NULL if I get the value inside jquery and print it. If I manually select that list using select all button or if manually drag select it all and if I tried, then I get the value. I need it to happen automatically after I transfer it to right side box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a javascript/jquery method for selecting the values on the second list while submitting the form

for you optiontransferselect tag, specify any for the doubleId attribute and use that id for selecting the values while submitting to the action..

I will paste what i have done...

javascript code is...

function selectJobLocation(){

```
var list = document.getElementById("jobLocRight");
for (var i = 0; i < list.options.length; i++) 
  {
   //alert(list.options[i].value)
   list.options[i].selected = true;
  }
  return true;
```

}

Now the Tag i have used is....

```
                                            <td style="width: 100%; padding:10px;border:none">
                                            <table>
                                            <tr style="border:none">
                                                <s:optiontransferselect theme="simple" 
                                                size="10" doubleSize="10"
                                                cssClass="jobLocationAssigned" doubleCssClass="jobLocationAssigned required"
                                                allowSelectAll="false" allowUpDownOnLeft="false"
                                                allowUpDownOnRight="false" requiredposition="center"
                                                doubleList="{}" 
                                                list="#application['countriesList']" 
                                                name="jobLocation"
                                                **doubleName="selectedJobLocation"**
                                                **doubleId="jobLocRight"**
                                                listKey="id"
                                                listValue="name"
                                                buttonCssClass="optionTransferButtonCSS" 
                                                doubleMultiple="true"
                                                required="true"
                                                emptyOption="false"
                                                doubleHeaderKey=""
                                                ></s:optiontransferselect>
                                            </tr>   
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
```

generate getters and setters for the doubleName in your action and you can get the values..